# Why the if statement is not working here?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import random
import numpy as np

LOC = [0]*96
LOC[0] = 'H'
for t in range(0,96):
    if (0<t<32):
        LOC[t] = 'H'
        print(t)
    if 32<t<40:

        if (LOC[t-1] == 'H'):
            print(t)
            print(LOC[t-1])
            LOC[t] = random.choice(['H','W','I'])
        elif LOC[t-1] == 'I':
            LOC[t] = random.choice(['W','I'])
```

Here `if (LOC[t-1] == 'H'):` is not working even though `LOC[t-1] == 'H'` . The control flow is not entering that `if` statement. Are there any errors in any declarations? Seems like a very simple question, but i don't know why it is not entering that if statement even when it is true.

Comment: Look closer, especially for `t==32` (and of course then `t==33`).

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried printing t, it stops as 31

Comment: Just think what the if-conditions mean with t==32. What happens and especially what doesn't happen?

Comment: What happens when `t==32`?

Comment: @Austin Nothing is happening. It is executing till t==31, when it reaches 32, the code exists like it does when the condition is false. But in my case it is true.

Comment: The end result will be a list of 32 + `w` Hs, `x` Is, `y` Ws, and `z` 0s, with `w + x + y + z == 64`?

Comment: You have a condition in both of your if statements where `t == 32` will not execute any code. Remember, x < y is not inclusive of y, but x <= y *is*

Comment: @MichaelButscher When t==32,``` LOC[t-1]``` which is LOC[30] is 'H' as I have made ```LOC[0:32] == 'H'``` before. But still the code underneath ``` if (LOC[t-1] == 'H': ``` is not executing.

Comment: Why do think `LOC[t-1] == 'H'` is true for t==33?

Comment: Probably you want `if 32<=t<40:`, but we don't know what problem you are solving.

Comment: Your loop will always print indices 1-31. You are checking for indices 32 and above if it's H or I, but actually you are just assigning 0 to them while initialising.

Answer (score 0):

If the latest index with "H" is the index 31, like you specified here:

```
if (0<t<32):
    LOC[t] = 'H'
```

you will never enter in this if, because the outer if starts in 33, then 33 - 1 = 32, wich have 0.

Comment: Thank you. I get it. I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, your if conditions do not cover t=32.. As a result `LOC[32] == 0`. For t > 32 LOC[t-1] is never equal to `H` or `I`.
Probably you want to include index 32 and assign value `H`

Comment: Thank you. I get it. I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set a condition for when your `LOC[t] = random.choice(['H','W','I'])` picks W, therefore when W is picked, on the next iteration `LOC[t-1] = W` and there are no condition triggered.

Add something like:

```
elif LOC[t-1] == 'W':
    LOC[t] = random.choice(...
```

Additionally, you skip the `t=32`

Answer (score 0):

The two conditions `0<t<32` and `32<t<40` are not adjacent.

When `t` is exactly 32, *neither* condition is true.

There is a "gap" of one element after the initial block of 32 `H` values, and so `LOC[t-1] == 'H'` is not true.

Comment: Thank you. I get it. I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 32 is excluded from your tests, and so index 32 will only ever be `0`. Let's do a smaller range to illustrate:

```py
x = [0 for i in range(5)]

for i in range(5):
    if i < 3:
        x[i] = 'H'
    if i > 3:
        x[i] = 'I'

x
['H', 'H', 'H', 0, 'I']
```

We've skipped over `i==3` because the tests exclude it. You want at least one inclusive condition here, but we can't tell which one that should be. This would be a `>=` or `<=`:

```py
for i in range(5):
    if i < 3: # this excludes 3
        x[i] = 'H'
    if i >= 3: # This includes 3 in the check
        x[i] = 'I'

x
['H', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I']
```

Comment: Thank you. I get it. I didn't see that